# What does this syntactically mean in groovy?

Tags: groovy

When I do this in groovy shell (2.5.8):

```
groovy:000> println("s":"s")
[s:s]
===> null
```

Why did my print statement print a Map (if that's the case)?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `println("s":"s")` is an example of passing [Named parameters](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_named_parameters_2), which are interpreted as a `Map`.

> Like constructors, normal methods can also be called with named parameters. To support this notation, a convention is used where the first argument to the method is a `Map`.

So you have a parameter named `s` with a value that is also `s` and Groovy puts them into a `Map` for you, per the documentation linked above. You could add additional named parameters to the method call, which will also be added to the `Map`. This syntax is valid for any method that accepts a `Map` as its first argument. In the case of `println`, it accepts `Object`, and since `Map` is an `Object`, named parameters can be passed to this method.

Comment: I thought our named parameter stuff was only engaged if the first declared parameter to the method is of type `Map`, which isn't the case with `println`.  Am I mistaken about that?  I thought this was just a `Map` being passed to a method, not engaging the named parameter support.

Comment: I'm not able to find any documentation of [Optionality](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_optionality) regarding the brackets around a `Map`, which leads me to believe the syntax `"s":"s"` is rather a named parameter.

Comment: Does `println("s":"s")` take a different path than `println(["s":"s"])`?

Comment: I really thought we only invoked the named parameter stuff if the declared parameter type in the method definition was a `Map`.  TIL.  I have deleted my answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you see is an omission of square brackets in Map literal in Groovy.

The call can be rewritten as:

```
println( [ "aa":"bb" ] ) // all brackets in place
println "a":"bb" // no brackets at all
println a:"bb" // a variant, where the left part of : is treated as key in Map Literal
```